# A collection/Data Structure which prevents deletion and allows insertion and read only functionality

Tags: java, collections

I want your help for creating a ***data structure/ Collection*** which supports read and insert functionality and **prevents deletion/removal** of records.
One way i could think of is , to create a customized collection ( *like myHashMap* ) and override all the delete/remove methods and thus prevent removal/deletion of records? But this approach will not work if the Object is having removal method as Final.
Please suggest any better way ..!!!!

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. Create a class that `implements Map` and _wraps_ a fully mutable `Map`. Then just delegate the calls you allow and not the ones you do not. Incidentally, this is exactly how `Collections.unmodifiableMap` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own arraylist by overriding the methods like remove() with unsupported operation exception. If you want you can also declare arraylist like this.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>() {

    @Override
    public boolean remove(String str) {
      //If you want, you can throw Unsupported operation exception also.
      return false;
    }
  };
```

There may be some other good approaches, you can check answers from others also.

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned in the question I thought the same thing. But , what if the remove method is marked as Final !!! Let's say I want to use HashMap and delete method is marked as final .. in that case this approach will fail.
I wanted to know if there is any better approach.

Comment: This is only for list type structure. If you want, you can create your map by extending the AbstractMap or HashMap and throw the exception. You can see the code for HashMap. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Map wrapper and provide only the methods you want to :

```
class MyHashMap<K, V>  {

    Map<K, V> map;

    public MyHashMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }


    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    // other methods you want
}
```

example:

```
MyHashMap<String, String> myMap = new MyHashMap<>(new HashMap<>());
```